# How to override react-slick default style for one slider?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, react-slick, vanilla-extract

I want to display slick carousels with customized prev/next arrows and the position of the arrow.
I am using nextjs13, chakra-ui, react-slick, and vanilla extract.

I actually could customize the arrows' style by passing arrow component

```
const settings = {
  ...
  prevArrow: <Arrow />
};
```

and the position of the arrow by setting global css 'slick-prev'.

The problem is that I want to apply this position style for a specific slider only.
(there are multiple sliders and I want to apply different styles)

I have tried something like this using vanilla-extract class,

```
export const classname = style({...})

<Slider className={classname} />
```

but this does not work because the classname should be `'slick-prev'` to override the default one.

Also, ↓does not work

const settings = {
...
prevArrow: 
};

I've also tried creating css file

```
.slick-prev {
    font-size: 15px !important;
}
```

and importing that file inside a specific component but it affects sliders on other pages as well.

Does anyone know how I can override '.slick-prev' style for one specific slider?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set css command like following if you set font size of prev and next arrows in global css file.

```
.slick-next:before, .slick-prev:before {
    font-size: 15px !important;
}
```

Current next/prev arrow components are based on Icon component, so to change size of arrows, we should set font-size by using `before`
But if you use image or text button component for next/prev arrow components, I think we can use `style` or `className` in customized arrow components.
Please check following code.

```
const settings = {
  ...
  prevArrow: <Arrow style={{ display: "block", background: "red" }} />
};
```

Please check [customArrows example on react-slick document](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/custom-arrows)

Comment: yes, as you mentioned I can override style by adding the global css file (.slick-next and .slick-next:before etc..) but this method would change font size for whole sliders on other pages. I want to change the style for just one slider though. any idea?

Comment: I think for now we can only use the way to set id of html element.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the issue by wrapping slider with `<div id="id1">..SLIDER..</div>` and changing css something like `#id1 > * > slick-next {..css here..}`